# How to use variables in other .py files

Tags: python, ros

I have file A.py in a package with a class and a list as class attribute or class variable. File A run a loop to update value to that list. How can I get the list and all changes to file B.py (in another package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using only 'class attributes', the values are static, a simple 'import' should work.

For example, `proj/package1/A.py`:

```
class A:
    attr1 = "foo"
    attr2 = "bar"
```

Create file `__init__.py` in all directories: current, `package1`, `package2`

Import A from `proj` dir in proj/B.py:

```
from package1.A import *
print(A.attr1)
print(A.attr2)
```

Import A from non-parent dir, eg. `proj/package2/B.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("package1") # Run programme in `proj` dir

from A import *
print(A.attr1)
print(A.attr2)
```